# tres columnas por filas php

Tags: php, html, css, imagen

Hola quiero crear una galería de imágenes donde defina cuantas quiero que se vean, y quiero que se vean de a 3 por fila utilizando php

```
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <?php
            $numeroGato=10;
            for ($i = 1; $i <= $numeroGato; $i++) {
                    echo "<div class='row'><img src='img/gato".$i.".jpg' class='mediana'></div>";
            }
        ?>
    </div>
</body>
```

por el momento llevo eso y solo se ven hacia abajo

Comment: Y si a la etiqueta img le pones un style display:inline?

Comment: <img style="display:inline; "....

Comment: Si le pones la clase row al div, es porque usas bootstrap, entonces puedes ponerle la clase col-md-4 a tus imagenes para que salgan 3 en linea

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con esto.

```
.container-fluid {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin-left: -4px;
    margin-right: -4px;
    width: 800px;
    padding: 2px;
    outline: 1px solid;
}
.container-fluid .row {
    width: calc(33.33333% - 8px);
    margin: 4px;
}

.row .mediana {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Si estás usando Bootstrap, que parece que si, aprovecha su propio grid para ello.

Quita el row en cada imagen y ponle la clase **col-md-4** para que sumen un total de 12 columnas de ancho, de esa manera se mostrarán 3 columnas, y abajo otras 3.

```
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <?php
            $numeroGato=10;
            for ($i = 1; $i <= $numeroGato; $i++) {
                    echo "<div class='col-md-4'><img src='img/gato".$i.".jpg' class='mediana'></div>";
            }
    ?>
    </div>
</body>
```